# what is solution for this servlet error?

Tags: java

`HTTP Status 500 -`
    type Exception report
    message
    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from
    fulfilling    this request.
    exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:221)
com.FileListServletkeyn.doPost(FileListServletkeyn.java:93)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.41  
logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
```

Comment: send ans as early as possible

Comment: @AmolSawant, please pay attention on your comments. Read the latest comment again...

Comment: Holy moly, man. It's *impossible* (or maybe not...) to help you unless you give more information. A NPE can be caused by *anything*, and we aren't wizards who can see what you're looking at.

Comment: @user3580294 I agree that the code should be in the question. But it's actually easy to find the problem even without the code, since the exception stack trace tells what the problem is.

Comment: @AmolSawant: please stop asking for a fast solution. Try to find it by yourself while people are examining your problem and helping you for free. We're not at your service.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, didn't expect it to be *that* easy. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to read the stack trace you posted, and the documentation of the classes you're using, to know what the problem is. The stack trace says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
```

That means that the exception is thrown by the constructor of StringTokenizer. So let's read [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29):

> public StringTokenizer(String str,
>                  String delim,
>                  boolean returnDelims)
>
> Throws:
>      NullPointerException - if str is null

See, it isn't hard. If you can read, you can find the problem. Avoid passing `null` for the `str` argument of the StringTokenizer constructor.